# How to redirect to another Server from SpringController with Request Parameters

Tags: spring-mvc, servlets

Could any one suggest me that how to redirect to another server from spring MVC Controller?

I could redirect to another server by adding the below code in my controller

```
redirect:http://www.okay.com
```

but the problem is I would like to receive the request with parameters in another server.

Comment: Append the parameters in form of query string: `http://www.okay.com/foo?param1=value1&param2=value2...`

Comment: That way the parameters will be visible on browser. I want to hidden all the parameters.

Comment: A redirect is a GET request, there's no other way to pass the parameters. Unless you execute a POST request and pass the parameter encoded, but this means you won't do a redirect. You should specify more about your real functional requirement.

Comment: I need to redirect to another server(Vendor server) from form but before redirecting I have to encrypt the parameters and send the encryption value as an one another parameter to the vendor server. So What I am doing here On submit of form I ll get the request to my server, after encryption I would like to redirect to the vendor server.

Comment: Then you just need to append the encripted parameter in form of query string...

Comment: I am encrypting at server side , On Submit I want to do the both action, so I can make bit user friendly view.

Comment: I understand that but looks like you're not understanding the proposed solution: in your server side, you encrypt the data, then use a sendRedirect (or another mechanism that redirects to your view) and **append** the parameters in the URL as query string.

Answer (score 0):

For using GET ,parameters can not be hidden. You can redirect through POST method.
Go through example :

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView postRedirect(){
     String redirectUrl = "http://www.okay.com";
     RedirectView vf = new RedirectView(redirectUrl);
     vf.setStatusCode(HttpStatus.TEMPORARY_REDIRECT);
     ModelAndView md = new ModelAndView(vf);
     md.addObject("param1", "hello"); //Add your params here
     return md;
}
```